# Convert a string of float arrays into an ndarray

Tags: python, string, list, multidimensional-array

Imagine one has to convert an ndarray into a string, then he has to convert the string back into an ndarray. For example, you have this string:

```
[1.1463377809323188, -5.631205546574898, 2.2669977232047676][4.579898563059968, 7.903827618691004, -6.286433358859447]
```

How could one conver this into an ndarray like so:

```
[[ 1.14633778 -5.63120555  2.26699772]
 [ 4.57989856  7.90382762 -6.28643336]]
```

I was thinking of converting the str into a list, then convert the list into an ndarray. However, the `str.split()` method yield me this:

```
['[1.1463377809323188,', '-5.631205546574898,', '2.2669977232047676][4.579898563059968,', '7.903827618691004,', '-6.286433358859447]']
```

When I try `split('[]')` now i'm left with only one element in the list:

```
['[2.182687926670855, -6.165595264315509, 2.0514527771233135][-1.9916686860482642, 6.353279016100898, -2.237430822379459]']
```

Comment: Why convert to a string at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
string = "[1.1463377809323188, -5.631205546574898, 2.2669977232047676][4.579898563059968, 7.903827618691004, -6.286433358859447]"
>>> [[float(x.strip()) for x in row.replace("[","").split(",")] for row in string.split("]") if len(row.strip())>0]
[[1.1463377809323188, -5.631205546574898, 2.2669977232047676],
 [4.579898563059968, 7.903827618691004, -6.286433358859447]]
```